# Does Hibernate CreateNativeQuery allow JSON cast?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpql, nativequery

Using **Java** and **Hibernate 6.1.7 Final**:

Is it possible to use a JSON key in the select statement when using `createNativeQuery()`?

Example:

```
Query<Object[]> query = new SessionManager().fetch()
    .createNativeQuery(
        "select contactid, flag::jsonb->>'priority' as priority from contact", 
         Object[].class);
```

Stepping through the program, I can see that `query.sqlString` is:

```
select contactid, flag:jsonb->>'priority' as priority from contact
```

Even though `query.originalSqlString` is:

```
select contactid, flag::jsonb->>'priority' as priority from contact
```

Exception:

> 16-May-2023 11:18:34.801 ERROR [http-nio-65501-exec-8] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
> Position: 31
> jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : JDBC exception executing SQL [select
> contactid,
> flag:jsonb->>'priority' as priority
> from
> contact]
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:165)
> ...

Why is the other colon removed?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I would report this. It's true, as Mark states, that `:name` is supposed to be parsed in native SQL queries in JPA.</s>

But I would say that we should be *easily* able to recognize `::` and leave it alone.

So I would call this a bug.

#### UPDATE

So, it turns out that this is something that someone implemented *intentionally* as an (undocumented) feature. The idea is that you can use a double colon as an escape to write a single colon.

I must say don't like it at all, and I doubt it's a spec-compliant thing to do. I would like to roll it back, but on the other hand it's been there for quite a while.

Sooooo, that said, you could write your query like this:

```
select contactid, flag::::jsonb->>'priority' as priority from contact
```

with *four* colons.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `::` cast operator in your native queries. Try a `CAST( smth AS target-type)` instead:

```sql
select contactid, CAST(flag AS jsonb) ->> 'priority' as priority from contact
```

Using a `::` cast operator leads to an error since `:name` is used to represent named parameters in the queries.